# best practices in pulling data from paginated REST API, page size vs. number of calls?

Tags: rest, pagination

I'm working on a project where I pull data from Github/Jira REST APIs where results are returned in pages. I'm new to the concept of pagination but I understand that it's better for the server side performance when the size of returned data is large.

my question is what's the reasonable page size if I want to make as less API calls as possible? and what's better for both client side and server side, to make more API calls or to pull more data per each call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach:

- in case of  UI application you can request the amount of data that is enough to full the UI screen;
- in case you want to make as less API calls as possible I can suggest following: three the biggest concerns of requesting big amount of data are response time, throughput and memory usage. 
  So if you have the requirement about supported requests per second and if you measure the required memory per request then you can calculate the maximum amount of data per one request. After that reduce that value to fit acceptable response time and throughput.